# Database table relationships with 3 entities

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, erd

I have three entities in our environment, **Account**, **User** and **Company**. Right now I have tables for account, account_user, account_company, company and user. It seemed fine initially but now that I think about it, it seems like it could be simplified with the joining tables.

- Every Account (portfolio) has 1 or more Companies and 1 or more User managing it
- User Joe Doe logs in to view Account Joe's Accounts with company(s) Joe's Company &&/|| Joe's Wife's Company

How would it be in Logical Design (designing database tables and relationships)?

Hope I described this clearly
Thank you

Comment: and that's why we have the concept of foreign keys..

Comment: @Aman I am using foreign keys, but thank you for your input

Comment: If you have many to many relationship between account and company & between account and user, then your schema makes sense

Answer (score 0):

This kind of schema might be of help to you.

- Table Company :

  > Company ID NAME DESCRIPTION ETC
- Table Account:

  > Account ID NAME DESCRIPTION ETC, Associated Company ID(foreign key)
- Table User:

  > User Details
- Table User_Permissions:

  > Users allowed on accounts

If you need one account to be part of multiple companies(which should not be the case) then you can make a bridge table for the account and companies too like for user permissions.

Comment: This would end up with duplicate entries in the accounts table though

Comment: No Duplicate entries. If you make a bridge table for accounts and companies.